# PostgreSQL add more values to existing row

Tags: postgresql

I am not familiar with SQL at all, hope someone can assist.

```
imss=# SELECT name, content from testdb where name = 'Test';
 name |                  content
------+--------------------------------------------
 Test | *@test1.com;*@test2.com;*@test3.com;
(1 row)
```

How do I add more values to the 'content' column? `WHERE name = 'Test'`?

```
like *@test4.com;*@test5.com;@test5.com;
```

Kind Regards,

Comment: This is a really, really ugly database design. Read up on database normalization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store CSV as single column then you should rethink your design.

```
UPDATE testdb
SET content = content || ';@test4.com;*@test5.com;@test5.com'
WHERE name = 'Test';
```

If content is text array then you could use `ARRAY_APPEND`:

```
UPDATE testdb
SET content = ARRAY_APPEND(content, '@test4.com')
WHERE name = 'Test';
```

Alternatively:

```
UPDATE testdb
SET content = content || ARRAY['@test4.com']
WHERE name = 'Test';
```

Comment: Magic! thanks that was exactly what i needed. Adding the addresses in the GUI stores it as the above format in the DB, guess that is how the application reads it.

Comment: The first query would also work if `content` was an array. The `||` is valid for arrays as well: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, I was not aware of that :)